# If-then expression and font color in Mapinfo label expressions

Tags: labeling, mapinfo, expression, font

How might I obtain the following, other than having two identical tables open to achieve: I would like to label an object using data from two columns from one table?

[image]

The first half of the label (from layer EN_FALL15:) will always be yellow bold font with black halo.

[image]

The second half of the label (from layer Cat_Priority:) would depend on the data in the layer:

When BLUE is entered, I would like blue bold font with white halo;

When RED is entered, I would like red bold font with white halo;

When YELLOW is entered, I would like yellow bold font with white halo.

Can mapinfo distinguish this difference and label accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have the layer four times in the map:

On the first layer, the label is set to be yellow

On the second layer, the label is set to be blue, and the label expression would be:

```
Left$(Cat_Priority, Int(Cat_Priority = "BLUE") * Len(Cat_Priority))
```

On the third layer, the label is set to be red, and the label expression would be:

```
Left$(Cat_Priority, Int(Cat_Priority = "RED") * Len(Cat_Priority))
```

On the fourth layer, the label is set to be yellow, and the label expression would be:

```
Left$(Cat_Priority, Int(Cat_Priority = "YELLOW") * Len(Cat_Priority))
```

As you will have to separate labels for the layers, I would recommend that you position them differently. Place the first right and above the insert point. Place the others right and centered (or maybe below) the insert point.